# unblock dell-wifi soft block

Tags: wireless, kernel, hardware, rfkill

rfkill list shows:

```
0: phy0 Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1:  dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
```

I already ran `rfkill unblock all` and yet still get the same results.  I certainly don't see any switch for wireless.

The Inspiron 1420 laptop was purchased a matter of weeks ago from FreeGeek, and they generally test the hardware.  While it could be a hardware problem, could this also be a software problem?  Certainly the second soft block should be unblocked, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The laptop has a hardware switch for wireless.  Try switching it on.  See image below.

[image]

Comment: jeesh, I'm sorry, I should've checked.  I looked it over carefully.